# R - Scatter plots - points() - positioning of data

Tags: r

Good evening all,

I'm having an issue with my scatter plot, I am placing all my points in a single area on the x axis but I want it to spread across the whole plot. First, here's a minimal example of what I'm working with:

```
data <- structure(list(names = structure(1:2, .Label = c("george", "harry"), class = "factor"), 
                       gender = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "male", class = "factor"), 
                       data1 = c(0.373, 0.37), data2 = c(0.376, 0.377), data3 = c(0.371, 0.361), 
                       data4 = c(0.3786, 0.3576), data5 = c(0.3262, 0.2928)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

#       names gender data1 data2 data3  data4  data5
#    1 george male  0.373  0.376 0.371 0.3786 0.3262
#    2  harry male  0.370  0.377 0.361 0.3576 0.2928

headers = c("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5")

names <- levels(unique(data$names))

bcol=as.factor(headers)

# colours
mapcol <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

plot(
  data[(data$gender == "male"),3],
  col=mapcol[1],
  pch=pch[20],
  xlim=c(1,1800),ylim=c(0,1),
  xlab="Names",ylab="Data Points",
  axes=F,cex.lab=1.5
)

###### This is likely where the issue is:

for(i in seq_along(names) ) 
  for(j in 3:7)
    points(
      data[(data$names == names[i]),j],
      col=mapcol[j-3],pch=pch[bcol]
    )
```

Here's an (edited to remove any confidential data) image showing what this code (and some later stuff that is just for drawing axes, legend etc) does.

[image: Image example]

My problem is this that I want the data to spread across for each name on the x axis, but is currently all just being displayed on "Harry".

Comment: Are you wedded to base plots or would you be happy with a solution that reshapes your data and uses ggplot?

Comment: I'd prefer to keep it in this format, as it will look similar to other relevant plots. Thanks for asking.

Comment: This is a little hard to tell given the small sample data but the `i` and `j` loops for presumably the full data, so I need to ask. `names` is a vector with the unique names, in this case 2 of them. When your loop is `for(i in 2:9)` and then you use `names[i]`, that means the first name never gets used because `i` is never 1. Is that intentional? Or you perhaps want `for(i in seq_along(names))`?

Comment: That's correct Gregor, I will edit the question so the code matches the example given.

Comment: Scatterplots need both axes to be associated with continuous variables. You don’t have the right data situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you are giving `plot` and `points` only a single value to plot at a time. The defaults will interpret the value you give as a `y` value, and assume 1 for the x value. You can solve this by giving an `x` value corresponding to the name.

```
plot(
  data[(data$gender == "male"),3],
  col=mapcol[1],
  ## pch was not included in the question, so this arg caused an error
  #  pch=pch[20], 
  ## key change: set the x limits to be 1 to the number of names
  xlim=c(1,length(names)),
  ylim=c(0,1),
  xlab="Names",ylab="Data Points",
  axes=F,cex.lab=1.5
)

for(i in seq_along(names)) {
  for(j in 3:7) {
    points(
      i, ## use i as an x coordinate, making sure i starts at 1
      data[(data$names == names[i]),j],
      col=mapcol[j-3]
      #,pch=pch[bcol] 
      ## pch was not included in the question, so this argument caused an error
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

The `points` function is vectorized, so we can also simplify your code to eliminate one of the loops. This gives the same result (though it does assume that the data frame is sorted in the same order as the levels - if you define `names <- unique(data$names)`, skipping the redundant `levels()`, then it will take the names in the order they appear in the data.

```
plot(
  data[(data$gender == "male"),3],
  col=mapcol[1],
  ## pch was not included in the question, so this arg caused an error
  #  pch=pch[20], 
  ## key change: set the x limits to be 1 to the number of names
  xlim=c(1,length(names)),
  ylim=c(0,1),
  xlab="Names",ylab="Data Points",
  axes=F,cex.lab=1.5
)

for(j in 3:7) {
  points(
    x = seq_along(names),
    y = data[, j],
    col=mapcol[j-3]
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `data.table` and `ggplot2`.
Step 1: Convert the dataframe to a long format using the `melt` function
Step 2: Use ggplot to plot the points

### R code

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

data=as.data.table(data)
data_long=melt(data,id.vars=c("names","gender"),measure.vars=c("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"))

ggplot(data=data_long,aes(x=names,y=values,col='variable'))+
   geom_point()
```

[image]

[image]